# Need to check class definition for a Package class, unsure if coding is correct?

Tags: python, string, class, constructor, instance-variables

I am not building the main program, just the class definition - so it's hard for me to check and see if my class definition looks correct.

**What I am trying to do**:
Create the class definition for a Package class.   Your class should include a constructor method, a **str** method which returns the package tracking number and destination zip code, the methods necessary to set & get the instance variables, a method which returns the volume, and a method which is invoked when a package has been delivered.

**Current Code**:

```
from datetime import date
from random import randintP

class Package():
    #constructor method
    def __init__(self):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.volume = self.length*self.width*self.height
        self.weight = None
        self.zip = None
        self.status = None
        self.tracking = random.randrange(0, 10000000)
        
    #returns volume
    def getVolume(self):
        return self.volume

    #returns tracking #
    def getTracking(self):
        return self.tracking

    #prints delivery date
    def status(self):
        print("Delivery Date: " + str(date.today())

    #returns tracking number and destination zip code
    def __str__(self):
        return "Tracking #: " + str(self.tracking) + "\nDestination: " + str(self.zip)
```

I am trying to create a Package class. What I have tried so far is shown above in my code.

Comment: "I am not building the main program" -- sure, that's fine. But you definitely should be building a [unit test](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase) for the class you're defining. I mean, you could _not_ write a test. But then, how would you know if the code works?!?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.